# How to create an ARRAY in an ARRAY

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have this code (created from the admin side) in my wordpress Database postmeta table.

```
a:28:{s:12:"featuredItem";s:1:"0";s:10:"headerType";s:5:"image";s:11:"headerImage";s:60:"https://rocks---.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/IMG_2051.jpg";s:16:"headerImageAlign";s:10:"image-left";s:3:"map";a:7:{s:7:"address";s:6:"Goslar";s:8:"latitude";s:10:"51.9059531";s:9:"longitude";s:18:"10.428996299999994";s:10:"streetview";s:1:"0";s:9:"swheading";s:2:"90";s:7:"swpitch";s:1:"5";s:6:"swzoom";s:1:"1";}s:9:"telephone";s:4:"0221";s:19:"telephoneAdditional";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:6:"number";s:12:"111111111111";}i:1;a:1:{s:6:"number";s:13:"2222222222222";}i:2;a:1:{s:6:"number";s:13:"3333333333333";}}s:5:"email";s:20:"goslarEmail@email.de";s:9:"showEmail";s:1:"1";s:15:"contactOwnerBtn";s:1:"1";s:3:"web";s:27:"https://musicheadquarter.de";s:12:"webLinkLabel";s:17:"Label of the Link";s:19:"displayOpeningHours";s:1:"1";s:18:"openingHoursMonday";s:2:"12";s:19:"openingHoursTuesday";s:2:"12";s:21:"openingHoursWednesday";s:2:"12";s:20:"openingHoursThursday";s:2:"12";s:18:"openingHoursFriday";s:2:"12";s:20:"openingHoursSaturday";s:2:"12";s:18:"openingHoursSunday";s:2:"12";s:16:"openingHoursNote";s:26:"Text zu den Öffnungsziten";s:18:"displaySocialIcons";s:1:"1";s:26:"socialIconsOpenInNewWindow";s:1:"1";s:11:"socialIcons";a:2:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:4:"icon";s:18:"fa-facebook-square";s:9:"iconColor";s:7:"#00FF00";s:4:"link";s:22:"http://rocks---.de";}i:1;a:4:{s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:4:"icon";s:12:"fa-instagram";s:9:"iconColor";s:7:"#00FF00";s:4:"link";s:20:"https://rocks---.de";}}s:14:"displayGallery";s:1:"1";s:7:"gallery";a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:6:"Bild 1";s:5:"image";s:60:"https://rocks---.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8797.jpg";}i:1;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:6:"Bild 2";s:5:"image";s:60:"https://rocks---.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8443.jpg";}i:2;a:2:{s:5:"title";s:6:"Bild 3";s:5:"image";s:60:"https://rocks---.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/IMG_8545.jpg";}}s:15:"displayFeatures";s:1:"1";s:8:"features";a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:4:"icon";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:15:"Feature Titel 1";s:4:"desc";s:28:"Feature Titel Beschreibung 1";}i:1;a:3:{s:4:"icon";s:0:"";s:4:"text";s:15:"Feature Titel 2";s:4:"desc";s:28:"Feature Titel Beschreibung 2";}}}
```

Now I tried to create the code for this ARRAY or what it is called. Everything works fine, exept the ARRAY in an ARRAY thing. Like, the list of social icons, image galelry and telephone numbers.

This is what I have so far:

```
$data = array(

    'subtitle'          =>  'Utertitel',
    'featuredItem'          =>  '0',
    'headerType'            =>  'image',
    'headerImage'           =>  'https://rocks---.de/wp-content/uploads/slide3___beach-2179183_1920.jpg',
    'headerHeight'          =>  '375',
    'map'               =>  array(
                            'address'   =>  $adresse,
                            'latitude'  =>  $lat,
                            'longitude' =>  $lng,
                            'streetview'    =>  '0',
                            'swheading' =>  '90',
                            'swpitch'   =>  '5',
                            'swzoom'    =>  '14'
                            ),
    'telephone'         =>  '0221',
    'telephoneAdditional'   =>  '0228',
    'email'             =>  'meister@rocks---.de',
    'showEmail'         =>  '1',
    'contactOwnerBtn'       =>  '1',
    'web'               =>  'https://musicheadquarter.de',
    'webLinkLabel'          =>  '',
    'displayOpeningHours'       =>  '1',
    'openingHoursMonday'        =>  '12-17',
    'openingHoursTuesday'       =>  '12-17',
    'openingHoursWednesday'     =>  '12-17',    
    'openingHoursThursday'      =>  '12-17',
    'openingHoursFriday'        =>  '12-17',
    'openingHoursSaturday'      =>  '12-17',
    'openingHoursSunday'        =>  '12-17',
    'openingHoursNote'      =>  'Zusatzinfos zu den Öffnungszeiten',
    'displaySocialIcons'        =>  '0',
    'socialIconsOpenInNewWindow'    =>  '1',
    'socialIcons'           =>  array(
                            'icon'      =>  'fa-facebook-square',
                            'link'      =>  'https://rocks---.de'
                            ),

    'displayGallery'        =>  '0',
    'gallery'           =>  array(
                            'title'     =>  'Titel des Bildes',
                            'image'     =>  'https://rocks---.de/wp-content/uploads/slide3___beach-2179183_1920.jpg'
                            ),
    'displayFeatures'       =>  '0',
    'features'          =>  '0'
    );

/* $data = maybe_serialize( $data ); */
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ait-item_item-data', $data );
```

HOw do I create the ARRAY for the Images, social icons and telephone numbers.

I unserialized the Field Data and it shows the ARRAY, great!

```
array (
  'featuredItem' => '0',
  'headerType' => 'image',
  'headerImage' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/IMG_2051.jpg',
  'headerImageAlign' => 'image-left',
  'map' => 
  array (
    'address' => 'Goslar',
    'latitude' => '51.9059531',
    'longitude' => '10.428996299999994',
    'streetview' => '0',
    'swheading' => '90',
    'swpitch' => '5',
    'swzoom' => '1',
  ),
  'telephone' => '0221',
  'telephoneAdditional' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'number' => '111111111111',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'number' => '2222222222222',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'number' => '3333333333333',
    ),
  ),
  'email' => 'goslarEmail@email.de',
  'showEmail' => '1',
  'contactOwnerBtn' => '1',
  'web' => 'https://musicheadquarter.de',
  'webLinkLabel' => 'Label of the Link',
  'displayOpeningHours' => '1',
  'openingHoursMonday' => '12',
  'openingHoursTuesday' => '12',
  'openingHoursWednesday' => '12',
  'openingHoursThursday' => '12',
  'openingHoursFriday' => '12',
  'openingHoursSaturday' => '12',
  'openingHoursSunday' => '12',
  'openingHoursNote' => 'Text zu den Öffnungsziten',
  'displaySocialIcons' => '1',
  'socialIconsOpenInNewWindow' => '1',
  'socialIcons' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'image' => '',
      'icon' => 'fa-facebook-square',
      'iconColor' => '#00FF00',
      'link' => 'http://festivaldate.de',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'image' => '',
      'icon' => 'fa-instagram',
      'iconColor' => '#00FF00',
      'link' => 'https://rockspots.de',
    ),
  ),
  'displayGallery' => '1',
  'gallery' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'title' => 'Bild 1',
      'image' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8797.jpg',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'title' => 'Bild 2',
      'image' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8443.jpg',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'title' => 'Bild 3',
      'image' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/IMG_8545.jpg',
    ),
  ),
  'displayFeatures' => '1',
  'features' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'icon' => '',
      'text' => 'Feature Titel 1',
      'desc' => 'Feature Titel Beschreibung 1',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'icon' => '',
      'text' => 'Feature Titel 2',
      'desc' => 'Feature Titel Beschreibung 2',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Now I need to know, how to create this part of the array. The number of images for the gallery is not fixed.

```
  'gallery' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'title' => 'Bild 1',
      'image' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8797.jpg',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'title' => 'Bild 2',
      'image' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/IMG_8443.jpg',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'title' => 'Bild 3',
      'image' => 'https://rockspots.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/IMG_8545.jpg',
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks for some tips,
Denis

Comment: What exactly do you want ? There are multiple values, So they are in array. Do you want to extract them or what? Be specific

Comment: I don't know WP, however, I could imagine it probably is something like `gallery=>[title=>'T1', image=>'I1'], [title=>'T2', image=>'I2']]` - assoc. arrays in numeric array

Comment: I am using a form that creates a new post. And this form content I like to have into this arry. Everything works exept the images. I dont know how to get them into the Form of that array. Will it be Done with a while next loop?

Comment: How do I creat that gallery array dynamic from post form content?